# Android room schema relation

Tags: android, sql, schema, android-room, relation

With my android room database, I have 2 tables: `order` and `service`, where  service is  either: massage, haircut, or spa. An order could have 1 or more services, I want my service table to just have my 3 different services. What is the right way to do this?

Should I be using `join`? `Foreign key`? `@relation`? `embed`?

I don't want any copies of services in my order table, because the detail/price of service could change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use foreign key for 1 to many relation (one order : multiple services). [This](https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-relations-75bbe02e8522) may help you and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/ForeignKey.html?source=post_page---------------------------#constants_1) is official documentation.

Comment: I checked before I posted this question. Most of these posts suggest having the relation id stored in the children(the service in my case), so if i have 2 orders with the same service, I would need 2 services in the table. I want to do it the other way around, where I only have fixed number of children(services), and have the ID in the parent(service in my case)

Comment: Then you need M:N relation. One table for orders, one for services and one table linking them. In this case you can have one service if it's repeating stored only once. Having it tourned around is not good because number of services can expand and you have problems then.